# Fetching Live update from cricinfo

Tags: regex, firebug

I am working on fetching live updates from http://www.espncricinfo.com/wcldiv4-2012/engine/match/576414.html and what I have been able to do is fetch the live scorecarads with wget and regex, parsing the "title" of the page (which is scorecard).

But I am not able to fetch the commentary which when I use "firebug" I can see but when I wget to fetch the page those commentaries doesn't show up.

Is there anyway to use firebug with command line ? ( was wondering if I can then I could fetch those results.)

or what is the way to fetch those auto-update commentaries ?

Comment: wget http://www.espncricinfo.com/wcldiv4-2012/engine/match/576414.html
cat 576414.html | grep "<title>" | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'

Comment: nope not this one . . the one you are trying to fetch the data from espncricinfo . .

Comment: that is the one with the help of which I am getting scorecard. I haven't written anything to get the the commentary because when I wget I don't get that in fetched page.

Comment: The page must have load the with JavaScript then. You should try to see what the js is doing and try to wget where it got the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be able to use the following RSS on your site. You need to parse the relevant feed and and get going.

http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/rss/feeds_rss_cricket.html

I doubt if cricinfo has its own API that you could leverage.

UPDATE 1: Cricinfo leverages yahoo pipes and merges these feeds, you can also leverage the same and the get the resultant pipe in JSON or XML format:

A simple pipe is here e-g:

[http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?*id=tMcVGcqn3BGvsT*_2R2EvQ](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=tMcVGcqn3BGvsT__2R2EvQ)